# reading xml - java, dom

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a problem with reading data from xml using dom. I don't know why "System.out.println(nNode.getChildNodes().item(0).hasAttributes());" returns false... In my xml file this node contains attributes. Could you help me please?

This is my code:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class XmlParser {
    private String[] linia;
    private String[] wariant;
    private String[] przystanek;
    private String[] tabliczka;
    private String[] dzien;
    private String[] godz;
    private String[] min;

    public void readXml() {
        try {

            File fXmlFile = new File("c:\\file.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            System.out.println("Root element :"
                    + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("linia");
            System.out.println("-----------------------");

            Node nNode = nList.item(0);
            linia = new String[nNode.getAttributes().getLength()];
            System.out.println(nNode.getAttributes().getLength());
            int i = 0;
            while (i < nNode.getAttributes().getLength()) {
                linia[i] = nNode.getAttributes().item(i) + "";
                System.out.print(linia[i] + " ");
                i++;
            }

            wariant = new String[nNode.getChildNodes().getLength()];
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println(nNode.getChildNodes().getLength());
            System.out.println(nNode.getNodeName());
            int j = 0;
            System.out.println(nNode.getChildNodes().item(0).hasAttributes());
            while (j < nNode.getChildNodes().getLength()) {

                wariant[j] = nNode.getChildNodes().item(j).getAttributes()
                        .item(0)
                        + "";
                // if(wariant[j].toString()!=null)
                System.out.println("    " + wariant[j]);
                j++;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post example content of your file

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the child node at index 1? My guess is that your parser sees all characters between tags (newlines, tabs, spaces) as CDATA and parses them as CDATA nodes which do not have attributes.

Comment: Yes, you were right. But it is weird for me. It looks like every other attribute is null. Why does it work so strangely? I have to do "j=j+2".